# How do I add a button to 'accounts/context' through ‘vscode Plugin API’?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]
I am going to develop a plugin to add one or more buttons in the above position.

Based on the documentation I found, my 'package.json' looks like this：
[image]
After running F5, it did not achieve the desired effect. Who has such experience?

Comment: I don't think that the `Accounts` context menu is exposed to extensions.  It isn't mentioned anywhere in the api contributes page/

Comment: Yes, it's not mentioned in the official api, but I saw it written in this way, so I asked, how do I implement it?

Comment: I don't think you can.  That particular context menu has to be exposed by the api and I just don't think it is.  You can raise a github issue asking that it be made available to extensions.